# Magento 1.7: product images showing in localhost but not in server

Tags: magento-1.7, product, image, magento-community, server-setup

After uploading my Magento 1.7 store from localhost to server, some images are not showing in the frontend nor in the backend.

I checked the `<img src="">` property both in localhost and in the server, but they are not the same and I don't understand why, because the code that generates them is the same.

The template I am using is `media.phtml` under `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/design/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` , and this is the code generating the image:

```
    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>" rel="grupo">
        <?php
                $_img = '<img itemprop="image" id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(330).'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
                echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
        ?>
    </a>
```

But I get the following paths (example):

- In localhost (works fine): `/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/330x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/l/plancha-de-metacrilato-transparente-cristal-transparencia.jpg`
- In server (different path without my image): `/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/330x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg`

So as you can see, the two paths are not the same.

Why the piece of code `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')` doesn't return the same in localhost than in the server?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: check your media folder , does product image exist or not?

Comment: also check your media permissions once

Comment: The image exist in the same folder than it is placed in localhost. About media permissions, how should I proceed? I am a bit new at uploading websites to servers. Is it a setting in the server or a setting in the Magento Admin? Thanks you to both of you.

Comment: I checked in my server and the folders had 775 permissions. I set the permissions for all folders and subfolders to 777, cleared var/cache and still not working. Should I clear the `media/catalog/product/cache folder`? But then I don't know how to restore its contents.

Comment: In server, all files should be 644 all folders 755. Media and Var folders should be 777

Comment: what is the owner/group for the media directory?Web server user account needs to be able to read it.

Comment: I think it is able to read it, because some images are actually shown. The one thing I don't understand is why some images are shown and others don't. What else could be wrong?